# Statistical Tests in Functions (R)

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

Hopefully simple coding question: How do I include statistical test in a function. Specifically, I'm working with time-series, and I want to flag curves that are not stationary. I need something like this in R:

```
flag<- list()

for (i in 1:length(obsv)) {
     if adf.test(i) FAIL {
           append(flag, i) 
           }}
```

Edit with reproducible example:

```
>df

DATE          ID VALUE
2012-03-06    1   5.67
2012-03-07    1   3.45
2012-03-08    1   4.56
2012-03-09    1   20.30
2012-03-10    1   5.10
2012-03-06    2   5.67
2012-03-07    2   3.45
2012-03-08    2   4.56
2012-03-09    2   5.28
2012-03-10    2   5.10
2012-03-06    3   5.67
2012-03-07    3   7.80
2012-03-08    3   8.79
2012-03-09    3   9.43
2012-03-10    3   10.99
```

You can see, object 2 is stationary, but 3 exhibits a trend and 1 has a pulse at 3/09. I thus want to flag 1 and 3.

```
>library(tseries)

>adf.test(df[which(df$ID==1), 3])

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  data
Dickey-Fuller = 11.1451, Lag order = 16, p-value = 0.01
null hypothesis: non-stationary

>adf.test(df[which(df$ID==2), 3])

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  data
Dickey-Fuller = 11.1451, Lag order = 16, p-value = 0.99
alternative hypothesis: stationary


>adf.test(df[which(df$ID==3), 3])
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  data
Dickey-Fuller = 11.1451, Lag order = 16, p-value = 0.04
null hypothesis: non-stationary
```

What I want is to incorporate the results of the test in a function.

Comment: flag curves or flag variables?

Comment: You should give a reproducible example. Does your times series /observations are columns of a data.frame for example? can you also explain what do you mean by FAIL (precise the condition).

Comment: Flag curves-- sorry for the confusion.